# How to reduce select * from table_name query execution time for table with 200k+ records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, select

I have mysql table set in RDS and I am querying from my web application. The query itself takes more than 20 seconds while other customized operations takes less than 0.5 seconds combined. Is there any way to reduce the query execution time to 2-3 seconds?

I tried indexing but it doesn't help either.

```
$table_data = select * from table_name
```

I expect the above query to take as less time to execute as possible.

Comment: You probably have a large table and it takes time to move the data over.  Nothing you can do if you are selecting everything.

Comment: If your table is rawish you can perhaps increase the speed by making it more relational. As in try to find out if you can make your columns into their own definition tables and see to it that they're refered to as opposed to being repeated.

Comment: Can't say much without seeing sample data and structure really.

Comment: Is the end user really interested in 200k+ records? I don't think so.

Comment: @SalmanA Very good point. I doubt any user will read 200k rows.

Comment: it seem (not really lcear), that you store the complete table ins a php? variable. It is faster to get row by row and to process the data for each row. Question: Is `select *` really needed? Select only the data memers you need.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the thing:

- Your query has no filtering predicates (no `WHERE` clause). Then you are selecting **all the rows** of the table.
- Your query has a `*` instead of a subset of columns. Therefore, it's selecting **all the columns** of the table.

In sum you are getting the whole table, every time.

There's nothing you can do on the SQL side. Your chances now reside on the admin side of the database. Get more hardware (faster CPU), increase paralellism (more cores), a faster SSD maybe?

Alternatively, you could use caching on your app side. Run the query only once every 5 mins, and keep the rows in memory.